# Proper way to stack models when some models aren't always applicable?

Tags: missing-data, ensemble-learning, stacking

Suppose you have two (or more) models that you want to ensemble together. However, some of the models are trained specifically on very specialized subsets of your data. If you do the stacking with a simple linear regression where the independent variables are the model outputs, how should you represent that output of the specialized model? Should you just put a zero for the model output on cases where the model is not applicable?

Apologies in advance if I'm fundamentally misunderstanding how to do stacking, this is the first time I've tried it.